# How to save to a database (derby) JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish, derby

i am trying to learn how to use jsf with database, i have some experience with JSF but nothing to do with databases,

what i am trying to do is make a simple page where a user enters some details and then this gets stored into a database, and maybe at a late stage could edit and delete these a simple CRUD program if you like

currently i have this xhtml page

```
                         <h:outputText value="Enter your username : " />
                        <h:inputText value="#{getDetails.username}" required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="Username is required" />

                        <h:outputText value="Enter your first name : " />
                        <h:inputText value="#{getDetails.name}" required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="First name is required" />

                        <h:outputText value="Enter your surname : " />
                        <h:inputText value="#{getDetails.surname}" required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="Surname is required" />

                        <h:outputText value="Enter email address : "/>
                        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{getDetails.email}" 
                                     size="20" required="true" label="Email Address">
                            <f:validator validatorId="richard.validator.EmailValidator" />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:outputText value="Enter your address : "/>
                        <h:inputText value="#{getDetails.address}" required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="Address is required" /> 

                        <h:outputText value="Enter a valid U.K. postcode : "/>
                        <h:inputText value="#{getDetails.postcode}" required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="A valid U.K. post code is required" /> 

                        <h:outputText value="Enter a contact number : "/>
                        <h:inputText value="#{getDetails.phonenumber}" required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="A valid phonenumber is required" />   


                    </h:panelGrid>  

                    <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{getDetails.add}" update="growl"  />  
                </p:panel>  

            </h:form>
```

the above page is just some input boxes for the user to enter their details into, i have some validation although i would like to add more later on, and the bean it is being sent to have all the getters and setters, and prints out the values in the console so i know it has been passed to the bean ok

what i would like to do is add these into a database, i have to use the one that comes with netbeans and JSF ( Java db, derby)

i have created a database and a table created to insert these values into,

```
CREATE TABLE userdetails (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  "username" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  "firstname" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  "surname" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  "emailaddress" VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  "address" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
"postcode" VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
"phonenumber" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);
```

all users must have an unique i.d. but they do not know this

i have set up in glassfish a new jdbc connection pool

```
pool name : airlinebooking
resource type : javax.sql.DataSource
database driver vendor : derby
```

in the properties i have

```
portnumber
servername
databasename
password
user
```

i am able to ping to database just fine

i have also created the jdbc resource

```
JNDI name jdbc/AirlineBooking
Pool name DerbyPool
```

is this set up ok using glassfish, i have followed a few tutorials to set this up

so the main question is, how can i get the values entered by the user to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Facelets along with all JSF focuses on user-interface, that's mostly view related issues. Database is *the other end* of application, and neither JSF nor PrimeFaces have anything to do with communication with database... However if you look around on [PrimeFaces showcase website](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) you will find how to provide some customized data to or from your user. That's not yet connection with database, but if you smart enough you should quickly find out how to use JDBC connections (here's [brief tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)), or even JPA/Hibernate persistence ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html)).